# How to priorities custom events on ng-click events?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive

I created an angular js app for the web.
I added an input text box and i added a ng-on-blur event.

Because i had problems with ng-blur i took custom ng-on blur:
it look like this in my code:

```
app.directive('ngOnBlur', function($parse){
    return function(scope, elm, attrs){
            var onBlurFunction = $parse(attrs['ngOnBlur']);
            elm.bind("blur", function(event) {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    onBlurFunction(scope, { $event: event });
                })});
    };
});
```

The problem is when i filled the textbox and click on other button in my app (fires ng-click) i.e.,
the ng-on-blur doesn't fire at all and immediately i go to the click event.

How can i change the priority to my custom event?

The html look like this:

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="x.y" ng-on-blur="doSomething()" />
```

I would like to mention that i add priority:100 and it isn't working.

Comment: `blur` and `click` event order is defined by browser. Angular just creates wrapper around it. And `blur` should be fired before `click`. Your code works correctly, tested in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/LgWmP/

Comment: I guess your code does not work because some other code on the page makes the `bind("blur")` function not work => cannot register event handler.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i change the priority to my custom event?

You can provide `priority` for custom directive you wrote. By default there is 0

But you can try this way:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="x.y" on-blur="doSomething()" />

     <button ng-click="init();">press  me</button>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.doSomething = function(){
       console.log('doSomething');
    };

     $scope.init = function(){
       console.log('init');
    };
});

app.$inject = ['$scope'];

app.directive('onBlur', function() {
    return {
            restrict: 'A',           
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
                    elm.bind('blur', function() {
                            scope.$apply(attrs.onBlur);
                    });
            }
    };
});
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/925/)**</kbd>

Comment: First of all thank you, but unfortunately it doesn't work. When i edit the textbox and click on other button , the ng-click is fires and nothing about the on blur.

Comment: See my edit, it works for me without priority (see console in Demo)

Comment: actually, the OP's original code works correctly. See my comment to the question with fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think now that i know why it doesn't work.

When i click on event. the event was on sortable element of jquery ui.
Maybe the sortable changes the priority?

i click on draggable element that looks like this:

```
<ul my-sortable id="sortable">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div ng-switch on="item.type">
             <div ng-switch-when ="x" ng-click="doSomething"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

the code of my sortable:

```
app.directive('mySortable',function(){
return {
link:function(scope,el,attrs){
  el.sortable({
    revert: true,
    stop: function(event,ui){
        ui.item.height("auto");
    }
  });
  el.disableSelection();

  el.on( "sortdeactivate", function( event, ui ) {
    var from = angular.element(ui.item).scope().$index;
    var to = el.children().index(ui.item);
    console.log(from);
    console.log(to);
    if(to>=0){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        if(from>=0){
          scope.$emit('my-sorted', {from:from,to:to});
        }else{
          scope.$emit('my-created', {to:to, index:angular.element(ui.item).attr("data-index")});
          ui.item.remove();
        }
      })
    }
  } );
}
```

}
     });

Please if someone knows that i should do....?